# how to Remove <a> and all other html tags from tha output string not at the time of input string in PHP?

Tags: php, html, string, tags

I am wondering to know how it can be possible to remove the tags from output string in PHP. At the time of input It can be removed by `strip_tags()` that I know but From already generated output where html tags appeared, How it can be removed ?

**For example** :

```
<p>Test paragraph.</p> <a href="#fragment">Other text</a>
```

**Screenshot:**

[image]

I have pointed what i am getting from database. Its like static text.

This is the output string appearing in my blog description. I want to remove html tags from the string. How can i be removed.

Sorry For poor english
Any Help will be greatly appreciated.

ThankYou

Comment: What do you mean by `already outputted`. Do you have any control to output something?

Comment: @shakti suppose i have used strip_tags at the time of input then the output will be like <a>text</a>. Tags will be shown. Now i want to remove that tags from output so that it will not be appeared. hope u understand.

Comment: @shakti I want to remove from already generated output string not at the time of input.As i exampled above

Comment: use `strip_tags()` before outputtung, e.g.: `echo strip_tags($your_string);`. i don't see the problem

Comment: not already generated buddy it is while generating output. You have to use `strip_tags` while outputting anything.

Comment: by using strip_tags. The tags will be shown. I want to remove that tags. I know about strip_tags() and allow tags in it..But it will be used during input and before output It is correct but if the strip_tags string saved in database then to view I want to remove html tags from the outputed string.

Comment: @GitsD, I think you are confused by what output and input are, and what `strip_tags()` does.  Please read the manual on the function. It works for ANY variable to strip out html tags, wether that variable is from `$_POST` or from database.

Comment: I don't understand the point w.r.t. a difference between input and output here.

Comment: @jakub I am confused because strip_tags is not working for me.I have tried these all stuffs.That is why I put this question here..

Comment: @GitsD, how about you post some code for us to see? Telling us "it doesn't work" is pointless and wastes all our time.

Comment: At the time of writing this comment, I assume that OP's question got resolved. But @GitsD you can use `strip_tags()` for both the time (while taking input or displaying output).

Answer (score 1):

If your blog is statically generated, you can run `strip_tags()` on any file in the filesystem, but the result is not likely to be very pleasant to read:

```
$str = file_get_contents($filename);
$text_only = strip_tags($str);
file_put_contents($new_filename, $text_only);
```

Comment: thanks for reply..but this is for blogs in file. I want to remove html tags from static text from database.Okay I think i should attach screenshot.

Comment: So load the data from the database, run strip_tags() on it, and write it back. The solution is the same, only the ways of getting the data in and out are different - unless we're not understanding the problem.

Comment: I have attached screenshot.ThankYou for replying.